# How to bridge mobile broadband and wifi networks?

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I'm using a **Mobile Broadband device/ usb modem** to connect my computer to the Internet.When I was using Windows 7, I made my laptop a **Wifi hotspot**, so I could surf internet on my iPod touch . Now I have moved to Ubuntu **12.04**. I read the tutorials and did everythig I could and finally ended up with creating an **ad-hoc network**.. My iPod Touch successfully connects to the ad-hoc network, **but I'm not getting any internet on the iPod**. I thought it's because I didn't bridge my **Mobile Broadband connection** with the **wireless connection**. So I changed my wireless connection's **method** to "**Shared to other computers**" in **IPv4 settings**. I can't download apps to my iPod touch.

Can someone help me share my mobile broadband connection over Wifi?

Comment: What you need is to setup a wifi network using. Setting Adhoc network is easy on Ubuntu

Comment: have you set up ipforward and iptables?

Comment: No I haven't setup ipforward. I saw it in forums..but I don't know how to apply those codes for my network types. Those codes are far beyond understanding for me. How do i figureout which ip address to choose? (My ISP provides me a static IP. Is that the one, or can I choose any? ) I did create a wireless network and a ad-hoc. Are you sure pforward and iptables will help me to solve this issue? Please explain..

Comment: See if this helps https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: Thanks. It did help... I got the simplified instryctions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is how I worked it out...

1. Create a new wireless network (aka hotspot) using the network manager.
2. Enable IP forwarding by executing the command below:

> echo 1| sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

3. Identify the device which connects your computer to Internet, by using **ifconfig** command. (My one is **ppp0**, because it has an IP address.)
4. Finally tell **iptables** to forward **ppp0**'s internet traffic to everywhere!

> sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE

Disconnect & reconnect the Wifi connection(Hotpsot) you made earlier.
Internet should be flowing to the wireless network now!
If you did it correctly, the output of **sudo iptables -L** should be similar to this:

> Chain **FORWARD** (policy ACCEPT)
> **target.....prot opt.....source....................destination**
> ACCEPT.....all  ---........  anywhere.............10.42.43.0/24.........state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
> ACCEPT.....all  ---........ 10.42.43.0/24......anywhere

An external guide is available [here.](http://www.howtoforge.com/internet-connection-sharing-masquerading-on-linux)

## Thanks to [web-E](https://askubuntu.com/users/35775/web-e)...!

Comment: Do you mean Ad-hoc or Infrastructure mode when you say "Create a new wireless network (aka hotspot)"?